# Use the Funnel Visualization report for multiple goals of type Event

Tags: google-analytics

In Google Analytics, there is a way to configure multiple goals of type **Event** to use the "Funnel Visualization" report?

I have several custom events that are being triggered correctly.  All these events occur on the same page.  Is there a way to organize these goals into a sequential funnel so that I can see how many users start at step one, the drop off rates at each step, and the total number of users who made it to step five?

I believe this is typically done using a **Destination** event where a **Funnel** option can be enabled and explicitly defined, but I don't believe I am able to do this since all steps occur on the same page.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't create a goal funnel or visualization based on a series of events. You can only do so using URL's at this time in Universal Analytics.

This is a missing feature that many would like, especially given the rising popularity of Single Page Applications.

In the mean time you can:

1. Add the extra step of rewriting your URLs based on important state changes you'd like to track (e.g. in an SPA or using GET variables for modified URLs)
2. Use Events Flow within Google Analytics *(found in Behavior ➜ Events ➜ Events Flow)*

Events Flow is shown below, it's a visualization that shows the sequence of events and therefore can give funnel-like insight.

Unfortunately, these event paths don't always lead the final event/goal you like, but it's the best alternative we have at this time.
[image: GA Events Flow]